# SharePoint 2013 Server Workflow Manager 1.0 Configuration Issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

While trying to configure Workflow Manager 1.0, I am getting below error. Could anyone please help me to resolve this.

Server Details:

Windows Server 2012

Workflow Manager 1.0

Applied CU1 for Service Bus and then applied the same for Workflow Manager

But while configuation, I am getting below error!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by missing trust between the context of the account (user) who started the setup and Workflow Host Manager service. The setup is trying to send the REST message by using SSL. Unfortunately the the certificate chain trust is broken. Following can cause this error:

1. Setup is trying to access the service via host header which does not correspond to certificate. host.domain.com is not equal host.com, if the certificate does not provide host-wildcards.
2. Certificate is not trusted.
3. Your Fiddler is running and Fiddler's certificate is not trusted.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13708.installing-workflow-manager-failed-with-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel.aspx

Another Possible issue is Proxy gateway. check this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/73a909d2-226d-454e-a8ca-c5e62dc8caac/setup-windows-azure-workflow-addwfhost-error-wfmanagementwftopic-and-token-provider-service?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: We are using wild card certificate and the same can be configured in another server allocated for DB. Recently we have provisioned another server for workflow manager, in that server I am not able to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is common issue. This happens when your certificate has, for example workflow.domain.com SAN and your server name is wfserver.domain.local. When you try to use the wizard it fails with an error:

**'...Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'.**

If your certificate is created for specific SAN, that would also probably mean that you would not like to use server name as workflow endpoint but some other DNS name.

If this is the case, then you have to do the following on your WF server:

Run:

***Get-SBClientConfiguration -Namespaces 'WorkflowDefaultNamespace' -Verbose;***

This will output the SB farm endpoint, and this is actually what is causing the issue.

Next

***Stop-SBFarm 
Set-SBFarm -FarmDns SPWorkflow.domain.com***

***Update-SBHost***

***Start-SBFarm***

Check if the endpoint is changed

***Get-SBClientConfiguration -Namespaces 'WorkflowDefaultNamespace' -Verbose;***

Add WF Host

***$WFRunAsPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText  -Force  -String '' -Verbose***

And finally add WF host to WF farm:
***Add-WFHost -WFFarmDBConnectionString 'Data Source=dbserver;Initial Catalog=SP2016_Prod_WF_Management;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False' -RunAsPassword $WFRunAsPassword -EnableFirewallRules $true -SBClientConfiguration $SBClientConfiguration -Verbose;***

Hope that helps